# Descargar pdf (BLOB) con select oracle

Tags: pdf, oracle-11g

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTO
( 
"clave" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
"precio" NUMBER(10,2),
"descripcion_prodcto" BLOB
);
```

El campo `descripcion_prodcto` contiene un pdf con una descripción del producto, necesito desde el SQL Developer (o cualquier editor sql) descargar esos pdf en una ruta, con el nombre de fichero que contenga `clave`+`precio`.pdf

Son unos 500 registros.

Lo he intentado con SQL Developer, pero solo me deja descargar de uno en uno. ¿Alguien conoce una forma de poder descargar varios a la vez?

---

Edito:

Con el siguiente procedimiento saca el fichero pdf, pero al abrirlo me dice que es un fichero erróneo:

```
DECLARE
l_file      UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
l_buffer    RAW(32767);
l_amount    BINARY_INTEGER := 32767;
l_pos       NUMBER := 1;
l_blob      BLOB;
l_blob_len  NUMBER;
BEGIN

SELECT descripcion_prodcto
    INTO   l_blob
    FROM   PRODUCTO
WHERE  clave='001';

l_blob_len := DBMS_LOB.getlength(l_blob);

-- Open the destination file.
l_file := UTL_FILE.fopen('RUTA','PRUEBA.pdf','wb',32767);


DBMS_LOB.read(l_blob, l_amount, l_pos, l_buffer);
UTL_FILE.put_raw(l_file, l_buffer, TRUE);
l_pos := l_pos + l_amount;

-- Close the file.
UTL_FILE.fclose(l_file);

END;
```

---

Abriendo el pdf con el Sql Developer y Adobe Acrobat se ve correctamente los pdf.

¿Puede ser porque el pdf contenga acentos y se codifica mal?

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Quieres descargar varios PDF a la vez o tienes un problema con los acentos o son ambas cosas? ¿Cuando hablas de 500 registros implica que hay que crear 500 PDFs? ¿Si es así, qué justifica que tengas que crear 500 PDFs de golpe? ¿Tu dispositivo tiene la capacidad suficiente para crear esos 500 archivos, en caso de que se justifique realmente esa creación masiva?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estas copiando sólo los primeros 32767 bytes del archivo. Debes usar un ciclo para hacer la copia completa:

```
WHILE l_pos <= l_blob_len LOOP
   DBMS_LOB.read(l_blob, l_amount, l_pos, l_buffer);
   UTL_FILE.put_raw(l_file, l_buffer, TRUE);
   l_pos := l_pos + l_amount;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: Efectivamente ese era el problema, gracias por todo.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa este articulo

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_read_pdf_file_with_oracle.htm

recuerda que el PDF debe ser legible (Diferente a una imagen)